# Cypress intercept wait, no request ever occured

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, cypress, e2e-testing, cypress-intercept

I'm having a hard time trying to mock a simple api request from a different port than the frontend.
The code below is returning: `Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: convos. No request ever occurred.`

```
cy.intercept("GET", "http://localhost:4000/conversations", {
  fixture: "conversations.json",
}).as("convos");

cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/conversations");

cy.wait("@convos").then((req) => {
  console.log(req);
});
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

#### UPDATE

I found the problem (but not the solution). Since I'm working with Nuxt, this specific api call is made with Nuxt's backend, so Cypress can't intercept it. Now I need to find a way for Cypress to intercept api calls made in Nuxt's backend.

#### 2nd UPDATE

So the "solution" I found on the internet is the one below. But it doesn't work for me. The frontend page I'm visiting is throwing an `Internal Server Error 500`.

in `cypress.config.ts` inside `setupNodeEvents`:

```
      let server: any; // static reference to the mock server

      on("task", {
        mockServer({
          interceptUrl,
          fixture,
        }: {
          interceptUrl: string;
          fixture: string;
        }) {
          const fs = require("fs");
          const http = require("http");
          const { URL } = require("url");

          if (server) server.close(); // close any previous instance

          const url = new URL(interceptUrl);
          server = http.createServer((req: any, res: any) => {
            if (req.url === url.pathname) {
              const data = fs.readFileSync(`./cypress/fixtures/${fixture}`);
              res.end(data);
            } else {
              res.end();
            }
          });

          server.listen(url.port);

          return null;
        },
      });
```

In my test before the visit():

```
cy.task("mockServer", {
  interceptUrl: "http://localhost:4000/conversations",
  fixture: "conversations.json",
});
```

Comment: Is your request from your API going to `localhost:3000` or `localhost:4000`? Your `cy.visit()` command goes to 3000, but your intercept is waiting for `4000`. (Definitely possible your FE/BE are running on different ports, just seemed odd at first glance)

Comment: my backend and frontend are running on different ports yes. Frontend is on 3000 and backend on 4000.

Comment: Have you validated that your application is actually triggering the request that you are intercepting? You could also set a blanket intercept to capture all requests and view that object after the tests run to see _what_ endpoints are being called and seen by Cypress.

Comment: Yes, the application triggers the request. The blanket intercept captures also the frontend visits so it makes everything fail. And when trying to intercept "http://localhost:4000/*" nothing is captured

Comment: Sorry, instead of mocking out the requests with the blanket intercept, you'd just pass them through -> `cy.intercept('GET', '**/*', (req) => { req.continue() }).as('blanket')`

Comment: Ok so I did this and it seems like cypress is not intercepting this api request

Comment: Hmmm - it might make sense to add an arbitrarily high wait (something like `cy.wait(60000)` to see if takes a while for the request to be made, while also looking at the network tab in the dev console (which _can_ contain requests that are being made that Cypress can't access)

Comment: Waiting doesn't seem to make any difference. Cypress is not intercepting my api call

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the full URL does not match correctly, but you can differentiate between port 3000 and 4000 inside the intercept.

Use `**` prefix to catch both port calls and dynamically assign the alias to the port 4000 call.

```js
cy.intercept(`**/conversations`, (req) => {
  if (req.url.startsWith('http://localhost:4000') {
    req.alias = 'convos')
    req.reply({
      fixture: 'conversations.json'
    })  
  }
})
```

Comment: **/conversations doesn't seem to intercept my api request. It only intercepts the frontend page

Comment: I found the problem. Since I'm working with Nuxt, this specific api call is made with Nuxt's backend, so Cypress can't intercept it. Now I need to find a way for Cypress to intercept api calls made in Nuxt's backend.

Answer (score -1):

Leaving this here for incase anyone else has this problem.

I had this problem ONLY when I deployed to Github Actions.  Locally it worked fine.

The key to getting this to work for me is that the syntax for Spying and Stubbing are quite similar, its easy to not realise you are actually trying to make a call from GitHub Actions (which I suspect is blocking network requests) and so it replies :

`Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: learn. No request ever occurred.`

So I changed:
`cy.intercept({ method: 'GET', url: loadingImage }).as('imageLoaded');`
To:
`cy.intercept(loadingImage, { fixture:`hero/${loadingImage}`}).as('imageLoaded');`

Based on this:

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Stubbing-a-response

And the comments here explain the syntax:
[Shows link on Cypress site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89rVS.png)
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Usage

Hope this saves you some time!